# How can I execute a Javascript function that is a part of a string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, function

I have a string called 'content' which contains HTML code. When a user clicks a button, the innerHTML of a div is set to the value of content however, if the string contains a function, I would like to execute it.

**Example:**

Function:

```
function state() {return "QLD";}
```

'content' string:

```
var content = "<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>state()<br>/div>";
```

Current Output:

> Example text here
>
> state()

Desired Output:

> Example text here
>
> QLD

Comment: sounds like a job for evil `eval` - but this doesn't sound like a very clever design to be honest

Comment: Dont use "" when you call a method..

Comment: You should simply write `var content = "<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>"+state()+"<br>/div>";` instead. Or tell us where that string comes from and why you need a function in it. Probably [what you are actually looking for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) is some kind of templating system.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a template framework, rather than doing this ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval()` function.

```
eval("2 + 2");             // returns 4
```

Of course, you'll have to figure out how to determine whether the string in your content contains a function and how to get just that string.  Also, remember that `eval()` is evil (i.e. probably dangerous) with user content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate a variable in there... then load it like this

```
var UI = {
  myLoad: () => {
     alert("works!");
  }
};


var myContent = "<span>" + UI.myLoad() + "</span>";
```

[Edited]

```js
var UI = {
      myLoad: () => {
      return "QLD";
   }
  };
  

  var myContent = "<span>" + UI.myLoad() + "</span>";
  
  myDv.innerHTML = myContent;
```

```html
<div id='myDv'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: You need to call it with `myVar()`

Answer (score 0):

Using a [*template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (also [*ECMAScript link*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components)) you'd do:

```js
function state(){return 'QLD'}

var content = `<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>${state()}<br>/div>`;

console.log(content)
```

But I don't know whether support for templates is sufficient for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The latest convention is to use template literal (backticks)

```
function state() {return "QLD";}

var content = `<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>${state()}<br>/div>`;

console.log(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking for possible functions. When you find that possible function, attempt to execute it and replace with what the function returns. If the function does not exist, then just replace with what looked like a function. In this case, you can pass a scope where the function may exist, in case it does not exist on the global scope.

```js
function checkFunctions(html, scope) {
  return html.replace(/(\w+)\(\)/g, function(match, capture) {
    try {
      return scope[capture]();
    } catch (e) {
      return match;
    }
  });
}

function state() {
  return "QLD";
}

var content = "<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>state()<br></div>";

content = checkFunctions(content, this);

document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the content string? Can you change that?
The better design would be to split the data up. Here's an example...

```
var content={
    html:'<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div id="jsContent"></div>',
    action:state
    actionTarget="jsContent"
}

 document.body.innerHTML+=content.html;
document.getElementById(content.actionTarget).innerHTML=content.action();
```

If the content is coming from an ajax call then have your PHP or whatever send you a JSON string

```
echo '{ "html":"<div id='jsContent'></div>", "action":"state", "actionTarget":"jsContent" }';
```

and then use JSON.parse to get the object

```
 var content=JSON.parse(ajax.resonseText);
```

In this case you'll have to call the action differently

```
window[content.action]();// all functions belong to the window unless you say other wise, replace window with wherever your function is if it is somewhere else
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your statements like this

```
function state() {return "QLD";}
var content = "<div>Example text here</div><div><br></div><div>"+state()+"<br>/div>";
```